# React performance: rendering medium size list with obvious delay

Tags: reactjs

I am experiencing a delay with react and react-router when navigating to a route with 250 repeated components.
I profiled with chrome and noticed the bottleneck is at the "ReactCompositeComponentMixin.mountComponent".
This function spends 36.1ms in itself and total of 570.7ms.

I noticed that visiting a route in react-router cause the assigned routehandler component (which holds these 250 repeated components) to reinitialize every time.
In this case, the state object of this routehandler component is Immutable but I cannot utilize the benefit from it since shouldComponentUpdate never get triggered.

I was wondering if this is an know issue with react.
If it is then I will try to render limited records a time on initial load and load the rest as user scroll down.

All components are "pure" and no complex computations are performed.

The html structure of the repeat component's is as following:

```html
<section data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553">
  <div data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553.0"><span data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553.0.0">TEST</span><span data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553.0.1">TEST</span>
  </div>
  <header data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553.1">
    <h1 data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553.1.0">TEST</h1>
  </header>
  <footer data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553.2">TEST</footer><i data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553.3"></i>
  <button data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553.4">TEST</button>
  <div data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553.5 ">
    <button data-reactid=".0.3.0.$3553.5.0 ">TEST</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you post your javascript code?  That will be more relevant than the html.  Without seeing your code, I would guess that adding a key to anything you are iterating over will improve performance.  Without a key, React can't compare to the current tree so it tends to replace the whole thing.

Comment: I second the opinion that adding keys to any dynamically generated list of components will speed up the render. Also do you mean that if you add a shouldComponentUpdate it is never is triggered?

Comment: JoeP and mattclemens make a good point about the keys, can you add   keys and let us know after testing?

Comment: If keys don't help, check this out. It aims to solve this problem by buffering the render until the user scrolls like you mentioned.. http://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are encountering this performance problem when rendering lists, my instinct is to think about [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Do you see a warning when you render your app?

I would advise adding a unique `key` attribute to each of the repeated structure.

The easiest, but far from the best way of doing this, would be to add the `index`

`arrayOfData.map((data, index) => <RepeatedComponent key={index} />)`

While this will assign a unique value to each `key`, there are [problems](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) with this approach.

The best way to do it would be to have a `id` as part of your `data`, perhaps a [unique identifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid), which you would use like this

`arrayOfData.map(data => <RepeatedComponent key={data.id} />)`

This would place the burden of generating the `id` and ensuring it's uniqueness on you, but it's the best approach.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question.

I solved this issue but forgot to update stackoverflow.
I forgot the exact solution but I believe adding key to repeated items always helps with preventing unecesseary rerendering of repeated elements.

Comment: Yes, it always does. For the reason that it does, it because the [reconciliation algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) of `react` uses a heuristic that essentially says, `the list is different after the first difference`. So, if you have `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and add `0` to the start, `react` will re render `1, 2, 3, 4` because when it compared `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` with `[1, 2, 3, 4]` if found a difference right at the start. With `keys`, it will know it doesn't have to re render the list, because the keys didn't change. If you find the answer useful, please select it as correct :)